# Does Install-ChocolateyZipPackage support basic authentication?

Tags: basic-authentication, chocolatey

Does the [Install-ChocolateyZipPackage](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/HelpersInstallChocolateyZipPackage) commandlet support [basic authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication), i.e. via an URL such as `https://user:password@example.com`?

Comment: Great question. Have you tried it and not found it to work?

Comment: @ferventcoder Yes we've tried, and it doesn't seem to work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no support for this at the moment, as if we pass such an URL (with credentials) to Install-ChocolateyZipPackage, our server responds with 401 (Unauthorized).

Comment: It's probably something that can be added. File a ticket on github? https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/issues/new